# How to overlay custom UI in Cesium

Tags: javascript, css, cesiumjs

How do I overlay custom UI controls in Cesium and move them to the right? If I put anything outside of `toolbar` `div` then I can't see any of my controls. I tried floating them to the right, they don't move. I would really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Try this: `position: absolute; top: 5px; left: 10px`.

Comment: Oops, meant right:  `position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 10px`